# Migration from Oracle to MySQL in Java Spring Application: Connection Pooling

Tags: mysql, spring, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am working with a Java Spring application that mostly does database operations. Inputs are database rows and outputs are database rows in different tables. Currently it uses Oracle 10g database. A new requirement is currently being analyzed, about migrating to MySQL.

The current oracle connection is setup using connection pooling. I am trying to do the same with the MySQL connection, and is researching on which `DataSource` to use. In the oracle connection, `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` is used. I thought of using `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` for MySQL, but it does not have the properties the oracle datasource had, and I have not worked on databases that long to know the equivalency of the properties required. The current properties setup is given below:

```
<property name="connectionCacheName" value="App_db_connection_pool" />
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="MinLimit">${MinLimit}</prop>
        <prop key="MaxLimit">${MaxLimit}</prop>
        <prop key="InitialLimit">${InitialLimit}</prop>
        <prop key="InactivityTimeout">${InactivityTimeout}</prop>
        <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">${WaitTimeout}</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

I need to setup the MySQL connection with the same or similar properties as above. What datasource should I use?

P.S.: The application uses a lot of queries in Java code, so using an ORM framework like hibernate is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I used C3P0 in the end. The corresponding properties look as follows:

```
  <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${InitialLimit}"/>
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="${MinLimit}"/>
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${MaxLimit}"/>
  <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="${InactivityTimeout}"/>
  <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${WaitTimeout}"/>
```